# jqmodal scrolling possible

Tags: jquery, jqmodal

Is there a way to make my jqModal scrollable? I'm loading the content via ajax if that helps any?

I tried adding the overflow: scroll and the scroll bars show up but it's disabled and shows the entire content.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
rodchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [jScrollPane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html). Looks pretty easy to use. You'd just call it after you've put the content into the div.

```
$('#selector').jScrollPane();
```

Comment: if you have other plug-ins like jquery.plupload.queue.min, jScrollPane() breaks the css. position:absolute works better as suggested by crickkills.

Answer (score 9):

Or if you just want your jqModal panel to scroll when you use the page's scrollbar, you can change position:fixed to position:absolute in the jqModal CSS.

Answer (score 3):

I just added a height (pixels or percent) and overflow: auto